# Update query successful but getting blank values in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database-connection

I am trying to create a job portal in ASP.NET that takes personal information from the user and stores it into a database.

The database table has these columns

```
 name, fathername, nic, cell, email, city, province, district, dob, 
 address, disability, orphan
```

At the time of registration, the user only enters the values for (name, fathername, cell, cnic, dob). After user successfully gets registered, they have to login and that takes them to the portal. The portal has a tabcontainer, in which the Personal Information Tab contains the personal information from the user. The information entered at the time of registration is already displayed in the textboxes and the remaining is to be entered using textboxes and dropdownlists.

The problem is that when I try to enter the remaining information using the update query, the query executes successfully and the values from the dropdownlists are being updated successfully, but the values from the textboxes are saved as blank values in the database.

This is my code:

```
protected void BtnSavePersonal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //    // inserting into database
    conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = connString;

    string query = "UPDATE PersonalInfoTable SET cell = @cell, email = @email, city = @city, domprov = @domprov, domcity = @domcity, address = @address, religon = @religon, gender = @gender, occupation = @occupation, disability = @disability, occupation = @occupation WHERE cnic='" + Session["cnic"] + "'";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cell", txtCell.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", txtCity.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@domprov", dropDomProv.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@domcity", dropDomCity.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtAddr.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@religon", dropReligon.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", dropGender.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@occupation", txtOcc.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@disability", dropDisable.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orphan", dropOrphan.Text);

    Session["cnic"] = txtCnic.Text;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        Console.WriteLine(query);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Redirect("Candidate Portal.aspx");
        Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Registration Successful.')</script>");
        personalFill();
    } // try
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Registration Failed.')</script>");
    } // catch
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Another problem is that once I have saved the values from dropdownlists to the database, I want some of the dropdowns (i.e province, city, district) to be disabled so that the user cannot edit that information again. I tried the following way to do it:

```
protected void editFalse()
{
    txtName.Enabled = false; txtFName.Enabled = false; txtCnic.Enabled = false; txtDOB.Enabled = false;

    while (dropDomProv.SelectedItem.ToString() != "-- Select --")
    {
        dropDomProv.Enabled = false;
    }

    while (dropDomCity.SelectedItem.ToString() != "-- Select --")
    {
        dropDomCity.Enabled = false;
    }

    while (dropReligon.SelectedItem.ToString() != "-- Select --")
    {
        dropReligon.Enabled = false;
    }

    while (dropDomProv.SelectedItem.ToString() != "-- Select --")
    {
        dropGender.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

The texboxes are getting disabled but the dropdowns are not. I also tried replacing while with if but that did not work either.

Comment: Try writing the Session variable at the top before your UPDATE statement. Since C# is a top to bottom approach programming language it may be possible that your UPDATE query is not recognizing the Session variable.

For disabling the dropdown list you can use jquery. You can take the id of the dropdown and on the submit click, add an 'disabled' attribute. See if this helps.

Comment: @RohanRao but the values from the dropdowns are updated in the database, the problem is only with the textboxes. So i think the session variable is being recognized or it would not update anything.

Comment: related - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: You are using a while loop to check for a single value of the dropdown list.  If it does not equal to "-- SELECT --" then you are in an endless loop.  Change that to an IF and see what happens.

Comment: @JMabee I tried with if, it does not work with that either.

Comment: @SMor then what should i use instead of addwithvalue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Turns out the problem was that i was missing a postback check in pageload function. Therefore, the values from the update query were being removed by the values already present in the database and giving me blank values as a result. I just added the

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
}
```

to the pageload function and added the function for getting values from database and disabling the dropdowns in it. Solved both of my problems.